# Debugging Stripe Webhook Event

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I spend my weekend trying to figure out Stripe Webhooks, but still haven't found a way to debug the response. This is my current code:

```
http_response_code(200);

        // set stripe api key
        Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        $endpoint_secret = 'whsec_XXX';

        $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
        $sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
        $event_json = json_decode($payload);

        try {
            $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
                $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
            );
        } catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
            // Invalid payload
            http_response_code(400);
            exit();
        } catch(\Stripe\Error\SignatureVerification $e) {
            // Invalid signature
            http_response_code(400);
            exit();
        }

        $event_id = $event_json->id;

        if(isset($event_json->id)) {
            try {

                // to verify this is a real event, we re-retrieve the event from Stripe
                $event = \Stripe\Event::retrieve($event_id);
                $invoice = $event->data->object;

                // successful payment, both one time and recurring payments
                if($event->type == 'charge.succeeded') {
                    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($invoice->customer);
                    $email = $customer->email;
                    \Mail::send('emails.new-userlike',
                    array(
                        'user' => $customer
                    ), function($message) {
                        $message->from('info@friendships.me', 'friendships.me');
                        $message->to('info@friendships.me')->subject('Test');
                    });
                }

                // failed payment
                if($event->type == 'charge.failed') {
                    // send a failed payment notice email here
                }


            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // something failed, perhaps log a notice or email the site admin
            }
        }
```

This results in a error 500 so far... ._.

[image]

But that is not the problem, I had it working already. The thing is, I need to check a SEPA subscription for a `charge.failed` or `charge.succeeded` response and only on a successful charge, create the subscription.

How do I access a subscription-id within this webhook? Or better, how do I debug the response? Because even this does not sent a response:

```
http_response_code(200);
$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($payload);
print_r("test");
```

[image]

Comment: First, try to find out why it caused 500. You can send some dummy webhook event JSON to dev server from your own machine just for debug purpose. Then figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the simplest possible webhook handler first

```
<?php
// Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON:
$input = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = json_decode($input);

http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater

// echo the event id, evt_xxxyyyzzz
echo $event->id;

if($event->type == "charge.succeeded") {
   // you want the id of the charge rather than the event, ch_xxxyyzz
   echo $event->data->object->id;
}

?>
```

When you use the "send test webhook" function in your Dashboard, you should then see something like `evt_0000000` in the response (and `ch_000000` if the event type is `charge.succeeded`).

If you're still getting `500` errors that means something is incorrectly configured on your server, and you can get the full error in your web server's `error.log` (try looking in /var/log or your server's web dashboard)

Comment: The basic handler worked, but I did not receive any response. I got it working now, though. Before I open another issue: am I not able to send mails with \Mail::send? I use this across the whole system, but it throws an error 500 when trying within the webhook. A simple PHP Mail() works fine.

Comment: Stripe's SDK doesn't include a Mail class AFAIK. Are you using a framework like Laravel or a SDK from another company? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail

Comment: Everything works fine now, thanks! :) I had a bunch of errors but did not think of the error.log :/

Comment: Woohoo! Glad to hear all is well :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding something like a man-in-the-middle if you want to easily debug webhooks. For example, https://www.reliablewebhook.com/ allow to receive any webhooks, log them and relay them to your localhost or other web address

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).